# Delete Google Group posts by age

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups

I am looking into using a Google group collaborative inbox for unsolicited resumes (in Europe).

One important requirement for companies managing resumes, is that they should be deleted after some X amount of time.

I wonder if there might be a way to set content policies on groups, such that a post will be auto-deleted at a certain age. Or maybe a Google App script can achieve this?

EDIT:

My research:

- I have gone through obvious configuration options on the Google Group page.
- I have done a general search on the web on the topic.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thank you for notifying me. I have added a short description.

Comment: Just covering the bases... Would you please confirm that you _are_ using Google for Business or GSuite.

Comment: This would be other resources that you would want to review [Groups Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups#resource) and [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference)

Comment: I suspect the Google groups settings/API features are shared across all account types, but we are using GSuite.